# Capture Terraform provisioner output?

Tags: terraform

**Use Case**

Trying to provision a (Docker Swarm or Consul) cluster where initializing the cluster first occurs on one node, which generates some token, which then needs to be used by other nodes joining the cluster. Key thing being that nodes 1 and 2 shouldn't attempt to join the cluster until the join key has been generated by node 0.

Eg. on node 0, running `docker swarm init ...` will return a *join token*. Then on nodes 1 and 2, you'd need to pass that token to the same command, like `docker swarm init ${JOIN_TOKEN} ${NODE_0_IP_ADDRESS}:{SOME_PORT}`. And magic, you've got a neat little cluster...

**Attempts So Far**

- Tried initializing all nodes with the AWS SDK installed, and storing the join key from node 0 on S3, then fetching that join key on other nodes. This is done via a null_resource with 'remote-exec' provisioners. Due to the way Terraform executes things in parallel, there are racy type conditions and predictably nodes 1 and 2 frequently attempt to fetch a key from S3 thats not there yet (eg. node 0 hasn't finished its stuff yet).
- Tried using the 'local-exec' provisioner to SSH into node 0 and capture its join key output. This hasn't worked well or I sucked at doing it.

---

I've read the docs. And stack overflow. And Github issues, like [this really long outstanding one](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/610). Thoroughly. If this has been solved elsewhere though, links appreciated!

---

PS - this is directly related to and is a smaller subset of [this question](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/610), but wanted to re-ask it in order to focus the scope of the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When I asked myself the same question, "Can I use output from a provisioner to feed into another resource's variables?", I went to the source for answers.

At this moment in time, provisioner results are simply streamed to terraform's standard out and never captured.

Given that you are running remote provisioners on both nodes, and you are trying to access values from S3 - I agree with this approach by the way, I would do the same - what you probably need to do is handle the race condition in your script with a `sleep` command, or by scheduling a script to run later with the `at` or `cron` or similar scheduling systems.

In general, Terraform wants to access all variables either up front, or as the result of a provider. Provisioners are not necessarily treated as first-class in Terraform. I'm not on the core team so I can't say why, but my speculation is that it reduces complexity to ignore provisioner results beyond success or failure, since provisioners are just scripts so their results are generally unstructured.

If you need more enhanced capabilities for setting up your instances, I suggest a dedicated tool for that purpose like Ansible, Chef, Puppet, etc. Terraform's focus is really on Infrastructure, rather than software components.

Comment: Arrived at the same conclusion you articulated above - I think terraform is a better fit for infrastructure components (only) while its better to leave the provisioning and bootstrapping-stuff-together to a tool better suited to handle that like Ansible. Thanks!

Answer (score 21):

You can redirect the outputs to a file:

```
resource "null_resource" "shell" {

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "uptime 2>stderr >stdout; echo $? >exitstatus"
  }
}
```

and then read the `stdout`, `stderr` and `exitstatus` files with `local_file`

The problem is that if the files disappear, then terraform apply will fail.

In terraform 0.11 I made a workaround by reading the file with external data source and storing the results in a `null_resource` triggers (!)

```
resource "null_resource" "contents" {
  triggers = {
    stdout     = "${data.external.read.result["stdout"]}"
    stderr     = "${data.external.read.result["stderr"]}"
    exitstatus = "${data.external.read.result["exitstatus"]}"
  }

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      "triggers",
    ]
  }
}
```

But in 0.12 this can be replaced with `file()`

and then finally I can use / output those with:

```
output "stdout" {
  value = "${chomp(null_resource.contents.triggers["stdout"])}"
}
```

See the module https://github.com/matti/terraform-shell-resource for full implementation

Answer (score 11):

You can use external data:

```
data "external" "docker_token" {
  program = ["/bin/bash", "-c" "echo \"{\\\"token\\\":\\\"$(docker swarm init...)\\\"}\""]
}
```

Then the token will be available as `data.external.docker_token.result.token`.
If you need to pass arguments in, you can use a script (e.g. relative to `path.module`). See

- https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/external/latest/docs/data-sources/external

for details. (Link update thanks to @TinyTiger)

Comment: This is a useful tool, but there's an important caveat in [the docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/external/latest/docs/data-sources/data_source): "Terraform expects a data source to have no observable side-effects, and will re-run the program each time the state is refreshed."

Comment: Note that this is the updated docs URL: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/external/latest/docs/data-sources/external

Answer (score 2):

Simpler solution would be to provide the token yourself.

When creating the ACL token, simply pass in the ID value and consul will use that instead of generating one at random.

Comment: This is a great solution whenever possible, but it's not always.  For example, [Rundeck API tokens](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/rd-cli/commands.html#tokens) can only be generated.

Answer (score 2):

You could effectively run the `docker swarm init` step for node 0 as a Terraform External Data Source, and have it return JSON. Make the provisioning of the remaining nodes depend on this step and refer to the join token generated by the external data source.

https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/external/data_source.html

Answer (score 0):

With [resource dependencies](https://www.terraform.io/intro/getting-started/dependencies.html) you can ensure that a resource is created before another.

Here's an incomplete example of how I create my consul cluster, just to give you an idea.

```
resource "aws_instance" "consul_1" {
    user_data = <<EOF
    #cloud-config
    runcmd:
    - 'docker pull consul:0.7.5'
    - 'docker run -d -v /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro -v $(pwd)/consul-data:/consul/data --restart=unless-stopped --net=host consul:0.7.5 agent -server -advertise=${self.private_ip} -bootstrap-expect=2 -datacenter=wordpress -log-level=info -data-dir=/consul/data'
    EOF

}

resource "aws_instance" "consul_2" {

    depends_on = ["aws_instance.consul_1"]

    user_data = <<EOF
    #cloud-config
    runcmd:
    - 'docker pull consul:0.7.5'
    - 'docker run -d -v /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro -v $(pwd)/consul-data:/consul/data --restart=unless-stopped --net=host consul:0.7.5 agent -server -advertise=${self.private_ip} -retry-join=${aws_instance.consul_1.private_ip} -datacenter=wordpress -log-level=info -data-dir=/consul/data'
    EOF

 }
```

For the docker swarm setup I think it's out of Terraform scope and I think it should because the token isn't an attribute of the infrastructure you are creating. So I agree with [nbering](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3771976/nbering), you could try to achieve that setup with a tool like Ansible or Chef.

But anyways, if the example helps you to setup your consul cluster I think you just need to configure consul as your docker swarm backend.

Comment: thanks for posting how you handle consul setup. I kind of agree regarding docker swarm setup maybe being outside the scope of Terraform - but it falls in the same vein of setting up a consul cluster, so if it makes sense to bootstrap Consul then I'd say it makes sense to bootstrap Docker Swarm as well. Still contemplating that... Also, unfortunately with the latest Docker Swarm (as of 1.13) the backends aren't configurable any more en lieu of Swarm's own distributed state store. Anyways - thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

[Sparrowform](https://github.com/melezhik/sparrowform) - is a lightweight provisioner for Terraform based infrastructure can handle your case. Here is example for aws ec2 instances.

Assuming we have 3 ec2 instances for consul cluster: node0, node1 and node2. The first one (node0) is where we fetch token from and keep it in S3 bucket. The other two ones load token later from S3.

```
$ nano aws_instance.node0.sparrowfile 

#!/usr/bin/env perl6

# have not checked this command, but that's the idea ...
bash "docker swarm init | aws s3 cp - s3://alexey-bucket/stream.txt"

$ nano aws_instance.node1.sparrowfile

#!/usr/bin/env perl6

my $i=0;
my $token;

try {

  while True {
    my $s3-token = run 'aws', 's3', 'cp', 's3://alexey-bucket/stream.txt', '-', :out;
    $token = $s3-token.out.lines[0];
    $s3-token.out.close;
    last if $i++ > 8 or $token;
    say "retry num $i ...";
    sleep 2*$i;
  }

  CATCH { { .resume } }

}

die "we have not succeed in fetching token" unless $token;

bash "docker swarm init $token";

$ nano aws_instance.node2.sparrowfile - the same setup as for node1


$ terrafrom apply # bootstrap infrastructure

$ sparrowform --ssh_private_key=~/.ssh/aws.pub --ssh_user=ec2-user # run provisioning on node0, node1, node2
```

PS disclosure, I am the tool author.