# Retrieve the value of a provisioner command?

Tags: terraform

This is different from "[Capture Terraform provisioner output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44509997/1220269)". I have a resource (a `null_resource` in this case) with a `count` and a `local-exec` provisioner that has some complex interpolated arguments:

```
resource "null_resource" "complex-provisioning" {
  count = "${var.count}"

  triggers {
    server_triggers = "${null_resource.api-setup.*.id[count.index]}"
    db_triggers   = "${var.db_id}"
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<EOF
${var.init_command}
do-lots-of-stuff --target=${aws_instance.api.*.private_ip[count.index]} --bastion=${aws_instance.bastion.public_ip} --db=${var.db_name}
EOF
  }
}
```

I want to be able to show what the provisioner did as output (this is not valid Terraform, just mock-up of what I want):

```
output "provisioner_commands" {
  value = {
    api_commands = "${null_resource.complex-provisioning.*.provisioner.0.command}"
  }
}
```

My goal is to get some output like

```
provisioner_commands = {
  api_commands = [
    "do-lots-of-stuff --target=10.0.0.1 --bastion=77.2.4.34 --db=mydb.local",
    "do-lots-of-stuff --target=10.0.0.2 --bastion=77.2.4.34 --db=mydb.local",
    "do-lots-of-stuff --target=10.0.0.3 --bastion=77.2.4.34 --db=mydb.local",
  ]
}
```

Can I read provisioner configuration and output it like this? If not, is there a different way to get what I want? (If I didn't need to run over an array of resources, I would define the command in a `local` variable and reference it both in the provisioner and the output.)

Comment: I've tried using console. `null_resource.serverless_deploy.provisioner.*.command` and `null_resource.serverless_deploy.provisioner["local-exec"].command`. Without success too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot grab the interpolated command from the `local-exec` provisioner block but if you put the same interpolation into the trigger, you can retrieve it in the output with a `for` expression in 0.12.x

```hcl
resource "null_resource" "complex-provisioning" {
  count = 2

  triggers = {
    command = "echo ${count.index}"
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = self.triggers.command
  }
}

output "data" {
  value = [
    for trigger in null_resource.complex-provisioning.*.triggers:
    trigger.command
  ]
}
```

```sh
$ terraform apply
null_resource.complex-provisioning[0]: Refreshing state... [id=9105930607760919878]
null_resource.complex-provisioning[1]: Refreshing state... [id=405391095459979423]

Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.

Outputs:

data = [
  "echo 0",
  "echo 1",
]
```